# "maximum depth of master-detail relationship exceeded" Can't change from Look up To Master Detail

Tags: lookup, configuration, master-detail

I have two Object, Current Relationship is Look Up I am trying change it to M-D. In change Field Type the field itself is "Grayed Out" with this Info.

My Intial requirement was Master-Detail because of Data First I Created Look-Up so That i Can change it to M-D

I have Double Checked it "All Child Record Have a Parent Value In Look-Up Relation" and there is only one M-D relation with another Object.

I can able to do it In Sandbox Even I tried to move the field with Change Set It is Not Validating Error is
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have seen this has been reported somewhere else also. If you are much sure that you are in the limits, better contact salesforce to check the limits by them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I am getting above Error Was I had Exceeded Number of Relationship i.e (Parent-Child-Grand Child-Great Grand Child)

The limit itself is 5 [If I am Correct Even In SOQL there is a limit For Child-To-Parent Query which is 5]

Even Salesforce Support Guys Also Told the Same Thing In the Case, there is no way of Increasing the Limit.

Again I have Written A Look-Up On Roll Up trigger On My Last Child Object to get Things done From There It's Normal Roll-Up Summary Field I've Used.

Even there is A Idea to Increase the Limit Which was shown by Support Guys, The Link for Idea I don't have now ,Tomorrow I will update the Link Here

Answer (score 4):

According to the docs:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_considerations.htm&language=en_US

> You can have up to three custom detail levels.

so it looks like you have exceeded that limit.

I have some orgs that required more levels of master detail relationship - to workaround the limit I use Anthony Victorio's roll up summary utility that replicates the functionality in Apex:

http://www.anthonyvictorio.com/salesforce/roll-up-summary-utility/

You can start hitting other limits once you get past 10 or so fields that use this utility - I've had to break some functionality out into @future methods in a couple of cases.