# Lookup Relationship - traversal level?

Tags: apex, soql, lookup, relationships

I would like to know till what level can a lookup relation ship fields can be traversed. 
For master detail , I could find 3 levels .

I tried this , but didn't work.

```
select id , Lookup1__r.Lookup2__r.Status__c 
  from CustomObject__c where Accountid='001L000000q9MfQ'
```

Comment: Often when I have relationships like that, it's missing the secondary, third, etc relationship.  If you're not getting the status, check to see if Lookup1__r.Lookup2__c == null

Comment: I guess your questions remains unanswered? Did you get an error message with what you tried? Is there any value in lookup1 or 2 for the account you are trying to query? Does status have a value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["maximum depth of master-detail relationship exceeded" Can't change from Look up To Master Detail](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44230/maximum-depth-of-master-detail-relationship-exceeded-cant-change-from-look-up)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**Understanding Relationship Query Limitations**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_limits.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_limits)

> In each specified relationship, no more than five levels can be
>   specified in a child-to-parent relationship. For example,
>   Contact.Account.Owner.FirstName (three levels).

5 level is the limit for child to parent

> In each specified relationship, only one level of parent-to-child
>   relationship can be specified in a query. For example, if the FROM
>   clause specifies Account, the SELECT clause can specify only the
>   Contact or other objects at that level. It could not specify a child
>   object of Contact.

Answer (score 4):

You can traverse up to 5 levels, for example, this from my code works:

```
Map<Id,Folder__c> parentFolders = new Map<Id,Folder__c>([Select Id, Name, Account__c, Account__r.Name,
                                                             Parent_Folder__r.Name, 
                                                             Parent_Folder__r.Parent_Folder__r.Name, 
                                                             Parent_Folder__r.Parent_Folder__r.Parent_Folder__r.Name, 
                                                             Parent_Folder__r.Parent_Folder__r.Parent_Folder__r.Parent_Folder__r.Name, 
                                                             Parent_Folder__r.Parent_Folder__r.Parent_Folder__r.Parent_Folder__r.Parent_Folder__r.Name 
                                                             FROM Folder__c WHERE Id in :feedParentIds ]);
```

Here is a related question (I don't think I have the reputation to link)
[Related Post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44230/maximum-depth-of-master-detail-relationship-exceeded-cant-change-from-look-up)